# How to prevent rsession crash when accidentally calculating on a wide matrix

Tags: r, rstudio

I work on somewhat large datasets in R, where I commonly have ~100 columns and 20,000-1,000,000 rows, typically with a single float/integer for each row and column.

Occasionally when I'd like to calculate sample-sample pairwise distances or perform PCA (or any number of other analyses) I will forget to transpose or untranspose my data and I accidentally calculate on a WIDE table instead of LONG --  instead of calculating pairwise distances for 100 samples, I'm calculating it on 1,000,000 features.

Once I begin a calculation like this, my R session hangs indefinitely, and won't respond to keyboard interruption until I eventually kill the process from the terminal and restart R.

Perhaps that wouldn't be so bad, but sometimes I have performed numerous calculations on that large dataset that take quite a bit of time to run, and now I have to re-run those.

NOTE: The situation I am describing is typically when I am running R from  RStudio - not sure if that is relevant.

**Does anyone know of a way to interrupt processes like this when they don't respond to keyboard interruption (or clicking the "Stop" button in Rstudio)?**

Comment: Haven't tried it, but `R.utils::withTimeout` may be one approach: https://rdrr.io/github/HenrikBengtsson/R.utils/man/withTimeout.html

Comment: Looks promising! I'll give this a shot and report back.